# Bad Message Number IMAP

Tags: php, php-imap

I am a php beginner and I am working on a mail parser. For that, I am going through PHP's IMAP functions which I wrote inside a mailParser class.

```
function __construct(){
    $this->stream = imap_open($this->server,$this->username,$this->password) or 
    die('Cannot connect to Gmail'.imap_last_error());
}
```

When I ran this:

```
function getInboxHeaders(){
    imap_headers($this->stream);
    $tot_msg = imap_num_msg($this->stream);

    for($count=$tot_msg;$count>-1;$count--){
        $header = imap_header($this->stream,$count);
        print_r($header);
    }
 }
```

inorder to get the headers of the messages on my Inbox, I was notified of the warning "Bad message number". Why do I get such a warning upon running this function?

Comment: What is $stream ?  You need to pass $stream to the function, right?  function getInboxHeaders( $stream ){ }.  If you have $stream defined somewhere above the getInboxHeaders function, simply pass it to getInboxHeaders. But you must modify getInboxHeaders to accept a parameter :  getInboxHeaders( $stream )

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. ``` $stream``` was supposed to be ```$this->stream ```. I also edited my question for the matter.